# how to automatically deploy to firebase on commit to main branch?

Tags: firebase, github, workflow, firebase-hosting

### The Main part

I am trying to create a comfortable workflow for myself. I just want to know is there any way to automate deploys from GitHub Repo to Firebase hosting when I commit changes in the repo's main branch at my desktop and push origin to GitHub?

*...possibly using "GitHub actions"...*

### Context and what I've tried

As on 15-Jan-2022 there are two ways I found of deploying website files to firebase hosting.

1. The de facto firebase cli way, where you use `firebase deploy` command to push files to firebase hosting.
2. The automated way using github actions, where the site is deployed automatically every time a pull request is created.

The first one is tedious, the second one is not my cup of cake. Especially because the workflow I want to setup is not too much *git oriented*, I don't use "pull requests" as far as I understand. I just commit changes directly in the main branch.

(That is so because, I am not a programmer, I just trying to create a blogging site using the Firebase hosting + GitHub repo)

I also referred https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-comprehensive-guide-to-github-actions-and-firebase-hosting-818502d86c31

Comment: I request, new readers to go through this comment thread to know why I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Deploy to live & preview channels via GitHub pull requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration). It will work if you use [pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) to review changes or if you push commits directly to the primary branch.

I would recommend that you use pull requests though. It's a great flow to double check your changes and with the Firebase action it will deploy a temporary preview of the the changes so you can validate everything looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for a kind reply, I understand from your answer that:
1. When we commit changes to primary branch, the deploy is automatically done on firebase from GitHub, when we use that method you mention 
>  Deploy to live & preview channels via GitHub pull requests
2. You are recommending this method.
But as I have mentioned, I am not exactly interested in previewing results and using Pull requests, because, I want to use Git Journal on Android to push changes to remote repo on GitHub.

Comment: That's fine. You can ignore deploy to preview and just use deploy to live.

Comment: I got the clarity now.